# dplyr returns negative subcript error for a subset in volatility calculation

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using `dplyr` to subset my data, and the `fTrading` package for `RollVar` to calculate the 62 rolling variance of daily stock prices.

I'm using the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fTrading)
x <- data %>%
  select(datadate, tic, prccd) %>%
  group_by(tic) %>%
  mutate(ret = prccd/lag(prccd)-1) %>%
  mutate(vol = rollVar(ret, n = 62, trim = FALSE))
```

and in some datasets I get the error:

> only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts.

I know there are quite a few topics already on the [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221310).

I cannot seem to figure out where my code is wrong since it works fine for some datasets and not for others (they are of course of the same type).

Here's a snip of the dataset:

```
  GVKEY LINKPRIM LIID LINKTYPE LPERMNO LPERMCO     LINKDT  LINKENDDT iid   datadate   tic  prccd   ccmbegdt
1  1045        P    1       LC   21020   20010 31/01/1962 04/01/2012   1 03/01/1995 AAMRQ 54.875 01/02/1994
2  1045        P    1       LC   21020   20010 31/01/1962 04/01/2012   1 04/01/1995 AAMRQ 55.000 01/02/1994
3  1045        P    1       LC   21020   20010 31/01/1962 04/01/2012   1 05/01/1995 AAMRQ 56.125 01/02/1994
4  1045        P    1       LC   21020   20010 31/01/1962 04/01/2012   1 06/01/1995 AAMRQ 55.750 01/02/1994
5  1045        P    1       LC   21020   20010 31/01/1962 04/01/2012   1 09/01/1995 AAMRQ 56.875 01/02/1994
```

It is a large panel data set, and I sort it on the ticker symbol.

Comment: can you share some data?

Comment: sure! where can I send it?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: you can use dput(data) and paste it in your question.

Comment: Okay, i tried to upload some of the data in the question. Hope that's what you meant.