# R doesn't like my coordinates - st_as_sf()

Tags: r, debugging, gis, coordinate-systems, r-sf

Trying to convert a data frame to an sf object via this post ([How to Convert data frame to spatial coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736577/how-to-convert-data-frame-to-spatial-coordinates/45484314#45484314)). However I keep getting the following error..
`` Error in `[.default`(x, coords) :  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts ``

I tried to resolve it based off of this post ([R debugging: "only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221310/r-debugging-only-0s-may-be-mixed-with-negative-subscripts)), thinking because my coordinates were global, R didn't like the range of values. However I subset it to just a the north western hemisphere and recieved the same error. Below is the code I'm using

```
dat.sf <- st_as_sf(x=dat2,
                   coords = c(dat2$centroid_lon, dat2$centroid_lat),
                   crs= "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

where dat2 is just the coordinates and a unique ID (group ID) for storm event associated with that lat and long.

UPDATE: I tried a few other things, such as:

```
coordinates <- as.data.frame(cbind(dat2$centroid_lon, dat2$centroid_lat))
dat.sf <- st_as_sf(x=dat2,
                   coords = coordinates,
                   crs= "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

and received this `` Error in `[.default`(x, coords) : invalid subscript type 'list' ``

and this....

```
coordinates <- cbind(dat2$centroid_lon, dat2$centroid_lat)
dat.sf <- st_as_sf(x=dat2,
                   coords = coordinates,
                   crs= "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

and received this `Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds`. traceback() tells me it is definitely an issue with my coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in the docs for `st_as_sf` you will see that the `coords` parameter should be:

> **coords** :
> in case of point data: names or numbers of the numeric columns holding coordinates

So you need to pass *the name of the columns* but you are passing *the columns themselves* . You will also see this is how `coords` is used in the answers you have linked. Therefore if you do:

```
dat.sf <- st_as_sf(x=dat2,
                   coords = c("centroid_lon", "centroid_lat"),
                   crs= "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

You should get the correct result.

Comment: This worked - always the simplest solution, isn't it?

Comment: @DPek Yes, but it's only simple once you know it!